# Deriving Point Estimate Based on Sample Mean with λ

Tags: probability, estimation

This is a review question I'm trying to solve. I didn't receive a direct answer, only a few tips from my professor, and I want to see if I'm moving in the right direction. It's a very general question.

The question is: Assume X1, ... , Xn independent and identically distributed random variables from the exponential distribution:

f(x) = λe^(-λx), x > 0.

Find an estimate of λ.

I'm thinking we have to use the point estimate formula:

sample mean +/- z*(std dev / sqrt(n) )

Then, we need to obtain E(x^2) and (E(x))^2 in order to find Var(X).

Var(X) = E(x^2) - (E(x))^2

E(x) can be obtained from taking the integral from infinity to 0 on the formula we were given multiplied by X by integrating for X. To get E(x^2) we do the same thing except multiply the formula by X^2 instead of X.

However, my professor said that the sample mean (x-bar) would be 1/λ, but I'm not sure where's she's getting this from.

Are my steps correct? Or am I getting something mixed up somewhere? I always appreciate explanations, especially since this is a more general type of review question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *population* mean $\mu = 1/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is
the rate used to parameterize your exponential distribution.
The standard deviation of this distribution is the same as its
mean.

See the Wikipedia article on 'exponential distribution.'
This article discusses two possible confidence intervals (CIs).
The one you seem to be considering is for relatively
large sample sizes and takes the form $1/\bar X \pm M,$
where $M$ is a suitable margin of error. This CI is based
on the normal distribution. This is probably what your
instructor intends.

*Note:* I think a better kind of CI is based on the exact distribution
of the sample mean $\bar X.$ It is the first one discussed
in the Wikipedia article. With modern statistical software
there is no difficulty calculating the confidence limits.
(Some printed tables of the chi-squared distribution may be adequate; this distribution is not symmetrical, so you have to find
upper and lower cut-off points of the distribution.)

*Addendum:* Consider distribution with rate $\lambda = .01$ and $\mu = 1/\lambda = 100.$ A sample of size $n = 100$ might have $\bar X = 93.57$ and thus $\hat \lambda = 0.0107$ (which is close to $\lambda = .01).$ The 95% normal-based CI is $(.0086, .0128),$ as we would hope--95% of the time.

Incidentally, but not relevant to the CI: The sample SD of these
100 observations is  102.59, which is also 'close' to $\mu = 100,$
but it is not generally as good an estimator of $\mu$ as is $\bar X$, and so $\bar X$ is used to find both the center and the margin of error the CI.

Comment: I forgot to ask one more thing, sorry, but were some of my steps correct? By that mean my method of finding the variance? I find the square root of the variance, plug it into the margin of error formula, and then get whatever the z-dist value based on what confidence interval I'm given?

Comment: No, mixing up estimate of \lambda and sample mean. Certainly on the right track. Please do reconcile with Wikipedia: If $\hat \lambda =1/\bar X,$ then CI is $\hat \lambda \pm1.96\hat\lambda/\sqrt{n}.$ You are not finding CI for μ=1/λ but for rate λ. See example in Addendum to my Answer.

Comment: I can understand how to do this with given values, what I'm not completely sure about was doing it with the given exponential distribution. Using that given distribution, would I find the expected value (through integration by parts from infinity to 0) and then set 1/λ equal to it? I have a note written down here that says E(Xi) = 1/λ.

Comment: Yes, you find the mean of an exponential distribution using integration by parts. Use the CDF (a vary easy integration) to chop off 2.5% from each tail. _At some point_ you should learn how to use such programs as Mathematica to get numerical answers. It is relatively expensive, but many math depts have it. For some purposes. R is as good--and free from r-project.org.